# How fix manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, cocos2d-x-3.0

First build eclipse project on cocos2dx/proj.android,how can i fix it.
I use eclipse and Xcode is OK.

### My build.Gradle(Module:project)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
        useNewCruncher = false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sinotech.boaigame"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 16

        ndk {
            moduleName "cocos2dcpp_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libcocos2dx')
    compile project(':yQY_PaymentSDK')
    compile files('libs/DataEye_Cocos2d_v2.8.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/JPay.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobclickcpphelper.jar')
    compile files('libs/umeng-update-v2.5.0.jar')
}
```

### My project AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sinotech.boaigame"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="83"
    android:versionName="8.3">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:replace="icon, label， theme">


        <!-- 友盟SDK的APPKEY和渠道号 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="UMENG_APPKEY"
            android:value="560369e667e58e8015004cbf_00" />
        <meta-data android:value="8B24BA16A672F2821847FC1425036875" android:name="DC_APPID"></meta-data>
        <meta-data android:value="hrhj" android:name="DC_CHANNEL"></meta-data>

        <meta-data
            android:name="UMENG_CHANNEL"
            android:value="202" />

        <!-- 友盟SDK的service -->
        <service
            android:name="com.umeng.update.net.DownloadingService"
            android:process=":DownloadingService" >
        </service>

        <!-- 友盟SDK的update -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.umeng.update.UpdateDialogActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity> <!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->


        <!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="cocos2dcpp" />

        <activity
            android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

</manifest>
```

The above code is the system automatically generated AndroidManifest.xml file.

What changes should I make?

I've read the official documents, but I don't understand them:[Merge Multiple Manifests](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these lines from manifest file:

```
 android:installLocation="auto"
 android:versionCode="83"
 android:versionName="8.3"

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
```